# Bootstrap Validation with custom validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

Thank you for your time!
I have a bootstrap 5 form with validation. One of the fields needs to meet 2 criteria: be 3 characters + unique.

The 3 characters long i did this way:

```
<input required minlength="3" maxlength="3" type="text" class="form-control" id="code3" name="code3" placeholder="AAA" autocomplete="off" style="">
```

As for the other validation, this is what i do:

I go through a values array i have and check for the key in it. if it does exists, i want the state of the field and the form to be invalid and for it to show the message for invalid.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var array3codesjs = <?php echo json_encode($array3codes); ?>;
   
    var specificfieldform = document.getElementById("checkagainstarray");

    specificfieldform.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();        
        var arrayLength = array3codesjs.length;                
        var ok = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            if (value == array3codesjs[i]) {                
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }   

        if (specificfieldform.checkValidity() !== true || !ok ) {           
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

    });
};
```

The code does work technically, but the state of the field is valid (as it meets the 3 characters part) and thus i don't get my unique test to stop the form.
Any ideas?

Comment: Since it's a manual validation, you'd need to show the error manually as well. Have an error span next to the input (with initially not visible) and then make it visible if the validation fails occurs.

Comment: thanks @SiddharthBhansali, but since the form still considers itself valid, the message "all ok" is shown and i think it will be allowed to submit once other fields are good. how do i set the form to invalid state?

Answer (score 0):

OK i found what needs to be done.

1. add "is-invalid" class to the non-valid input (this will cause the show of the error message by bootstrap.
2. remove "was-validated" class from the form (this removes indication for pure bootstrap validation, both focusing the user on the problem we just found + removes the valid message on the same field from bootstrap check, in my case = that the input is indeed 3 characters long).


   so here is the complete code

   window.onload = function () {
   var array3codesjs = ;
   var array2codesjs = ;

   ```
    var specificfieldform = document.getElementById("checkagainstarray");

    specificfieldform.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {        
        var value = $("#code3").val();
        var arrayLength = array3codesjs.length;                
        var ok = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            if (value == array3codesjs[i]) {                
                ok = false;                
                break;
            }
        }   

        if (!ok ) {              
            $("#code3").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#checkagainstarray").removeClass("was-validated");            
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            $("#code3").removeClass("is-invalid");            
        }

        var value = $("#code2").val();
        var arrayLength = array2codesjs.length;                
        var ok2 = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            if (value == array2codesjs[i]) {                
                ok2 = false;        
                break;
            }
        }   

        if (!ok2 ) {              
            $("#code2").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#checkagainstarray").removeClass("was-validated");            
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            $("#code2").removeClass("is-invalid");            
        }

    });
   ```

   };