# Bootstrap-5 custom validation issue

Tags: validation, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 for form validation. I'm adding the 'is-invalid/is-valid' class to the date field 'dob' in a custom date validation method validate_dob().

I tried doing the **date validation before/after adding the 'was-validated'** class to the form. In either case, the red border around the dob field does not show up if the date field is invalid. The error message does get displayed if the date is invalid.
I'm forced to add the red border around the dob field in the validate_dob() method and I don't like this. It appears that the 'was-validated' class is treating the dob field as valid since it has a date, but I don't understand why the error message is getting displayed if it thinks the field is valid. If I'm doing something wrong, please let me know.

The post below suggests removing the 'was-validated' class. If I do that, I lose the standard validation for the other form fields and that doesn't work for me.
[Bootstrap Validation with custom validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314299/bootstrap-validation-with-custom-validation)

```
    function validateDOB()
    {
        const age = calculateAge(dateOfBirth.value) ;
        if (age < 9 || age > 90 || isNaN(age))
            isDobValid=false;
        else
            isDobValid=true;
        
        let dobClassList=dateOfBirth.classList;
        if (! isDobValid)
        {
              dateOfBirth.style.border="1px solid red";
              dobClassList.remove("is-valid");
              dobClassList.add("is-invalid");
        }
        else
        {
            
              dateOfBirth.style.border="1px solid green";
              dobClassList.remove("is-invalid");
              dobClassList.add("is-valid");
              
        }
        
        return isDobValid;
    }

    async function createUpdateUser(event)
    {  
        event.preventDefault();
            
        //Check if the form contains errors or if there are custom validation errors
        const form=document.querySelector("form"); 
        form.classList.add("was-validated");
        if (! form.checkValidity() | ! validateDOB() )
        {   
            .....
            return;
        }
        ...
    }

   /*I didn't want the tick marks to be shown after bootstrap validation since it looked awkward with custom  validation done outside of bootstap
    The below two work with standard bootstrap validation and don't show the green tick mark
    */
    .was-validated .form-control:invalid {
    background-image: none;
    }

    .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    background-image: none;
    }

  /*This is required for custom bootstrap validation where we add the is-valid class. If we don't include this, the green tick still gets displayed for fields with custom validation */
   .form-control.is-valid{
    background-image: none;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

In Bootstrap 5, when using the `was-validated` class on a form element, it automatically adds validation styles and classes to form controls (input fields, select boxes, etc.) based on their validity state. However, it's important to note that Bootstrap relies on the browser's built-in HTML5 form validation for this behavior.

In your code, you have a custom validation function `validate_dob()` that checks the validity of the date of birth (DOB) field and updates its border and classes (`is-valid` or `is-invalid`) accordingly. While this custom validation function may work for your specific validation requirements, it's important to understand that Bootstrap's `was-validated` class is primarily designed to work with the browser's built-in form validation.

The issue you're facing might be related to Bootstrap and browser behavior conflicting with your custom validation logic. Here are some recommendations to resolve this:

1. **Use `pattern` Attribute**: Instead of manually applying classes and styles for validation, consider using the `pattern` attribute to enforce the date format directly in the HTML input element. For example:

```html
<input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" class="form-control form-control-sm" required pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}">
<div class="invalid-feedback">Age should be in the range of 9-90 years</div>
```

In this example, the `pattern` attribute enforces the YYYY-MM-DD format, which is the format expected by the `date` input type. The browser will handle validation and styling automatically.

1. **Avoid Custom Classes**: Remove the custom `is-valid` and `is-invalid` classes from your custom validation logic, as they may interfere with Bootstrap's styling. Let Bootstrap handle the styling based on the `was-validated` class.
2. **Custom Validation Feedback**: If you want to display custom validation feedback (e.g., "Age should be in the range of 9-90 years"), you can do so using the `<div class="invalid-feedback">` element, as you have already done.

Comment: Thanks, Ankit. I appreciate the detailed response. While I understand what you are saying, it doesn't solve my problem since I need to add a couple of custom validations. Since the Bootstrap 5 framework doesn't support custom validations, I will need to find a way out. Will think about it.

Comment: @Sara found a solution yet? pls share

Comment: You will need to add the red and green borders in the custom validation, but the form doesn't look bad because I used some CSS styles to get rid of the green tick mark that Bootstrap shows when a field is valid. I have updated the question with my code. Hope this helps.

Comment: If the field that has the custom validation is in error, then I'm displaying a red border around the field and the error message is shown in the <div class="invalid-feedback"> element. When you click on a field that has a custom validation error, Bootstrap will show a green border around it since it thinks the field is valid. So you will see a red border surrounded by a light green border, but as I mentioned above I used some CSS styles to get rid of the green tick marks and that makes the form look decent.